# Outlook JS Add-In - handling object save

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In using the new JavaScript API.

All is nice and works, but now I have a use case, that I want to save some custom data from my add-in side-pane when the user clicks "Save/Send" on an Calendar Event. I don't see any way to achieve that in the documentation, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Office.js API. You may vote up this feature for upcoming release at [Office Developers User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10964871-add-itemsend-event-so-add-in-can-cancel-email). Still nobody knows if it will be implemented any time soon. For now review the logic of your app to make it independent from Outlook events.

Comment: Alek, could you share your scenario?